# how do I code a filtered replication in pouchdb that will return more than 25 rows?

Tags: pouchdb

How do I code a filtered replication in pouchdb that will return more than 25 rows?

If I create a new pouchdb or delete an existing one and recreate using:

```
Pouch.replicate(couchdb,pouchdb,{filter: filterBySup},function(err, changes) {
     if(err){                                                       
          console.log(err);
     }                                      
     else {                                                                                                  
          function();
     }
};

function filterBySup(doc){
    if(doc.empSuperID && doc.empSuperID == activeUserID || doc.empUserID == activeUserID) {
              console.log(doc);
              return true;
         } else {
          return false;
         }
}
```

I only get 25 rows returned...

Comment: If I remember right the HTTP adapter pages through the changes while replicating, fetching 25 at a time. Could be there's a bug with filtering those changes that prevents getting the next set?

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is to go into the pouch.nightly.js file and search for "t = 25" and change it to a larger number that you would never expect the number of docs to exceed.